# Assign Username and Password to Web Service vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, web-services, credentials

I need to create a web service in vb.NET which has username and password.
In other words I need my web service has credential like a windows account.

But I don't have any idea how can do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the web service, simply add parameters for username and password.  For example the following webservice takes a username and password as a string, logs into the database with them and returns a dataset (the open connection function isn't shown).  I encrypt the connection with TLS 1.2:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net.mail
Imports System.IO

<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class MyWebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
        <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetData(ByVal pUsername As String, ByVal pPassword As String) As DataSet
        Dim MyDataSet As DataSet
        Dim MyConnection As OracleConnection = OpenConnection(pUsername, pPassword)
        Try
            MyDataSet = GetUserData(MyConnection, pUsername)
            MyConnection.Close()
            MyConnection.Dispose()
            MyConnection = Nothing
            Return MyDataSet

        Catch ex As Exception
            MyConnection.Close()
            MyConnection.Dispose()
            MyConnection = Nothing
            Return New DataSet
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks it’s exactly what I want to do.